# Rails sort list of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have list of categories
`@categories = Category.all`

There are about ten categories.
But I need to change order of them being displayed.

I need category with `id = n` to be shown first.
This categories already created and filled with items.
So what is the most elegant way to change `@categories` and put category with `id=n` first?

Answer (score 1):

`@categories = Category.order("id != #{n}")`